# GC problems with API lvl 10 and ScrollView

Tags: android, performance, garbage-collection, android-animation

I've run into weird GC issue having 2 layouts stacked, both contain `ScrollView` and their visibility is animated that only one is visible at time. After running animation to hide first, show second, then hide second and show first. Then scrolling first `ScrollView` GC goes mad giving:

GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 56% free 3340K/7559K, external 13894K/14442K, paused 19ms

This happens all the time, so scrolling gets so laggy.

Only seen with API level 10 emulator and 2.3.5 device. Anyone seen this behaviour?

Thanks.

[image]

Above picture is to demonstrate the setup I have. 5 `Fragment` stacked, and 4 are visible on start.

Comment: Concurrent garbage collector is introduced in Android 2.3. Can you show how you load your views in the scrollview?

Comment: My Views are Fragments with xml layout, so the content of ScrollView is stated in xml. The problem somehow seems to be connected to my custom view which is inside content, so I need to study this more.

Comment: But the problem occurs only after I run some animation here, so something goes wrong with drawing, because scrolling causes onDraw to be called all the time and that's where GC collects all the time.

Comment: Try to minimize Variables used in onDraw

Comment: Okay now that I removed all content, only have multiple Fragments which have 9-patch background and also ScrollView. On start there are 4 Fragments shown like a menu and all of them can be scrolled, after hiding all them and bringing other Fragment visible, then hiding it and bringing the start Fragments visible, scrolling any of them causes GC.

Comment: You removed content from onDraw? Please provide your custom View implementation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23571/discussion-between-niko-and-mohamed-abdallah)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting animation cache disabled for my `Fragment` view solved the issue, not sure why, but most likely platform 2.3.x bug.